# Let $n$ be a positive integer and $k \in \Bbb Z$. Show that $\langle [k]_n \rangle$ is an ideal for $(\Bbb Z_n, +, \cdot)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, ideals, cyclic-groups

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and $k \in \Bbb Z$. Show that $\langle [k]_n \rangle$ is an ideal for $(\Bbb Z_n, +, \cdot)$.

I'm always confused when we have two binary operations. How am I to know if by $\langle [k]_n \rangle$ they mean $$\langle [k]_n \rangle=\{[k]_n^t \mid t \in \Bbb Z \}$$ or $$\langle [k]_n \rangle = \{t[k]_n \mid t \in \Bbb Z\}?$$ These are both well defined so either one of them work. If I suppose it's the latter one then, for $a,b \in \langle [k]_n \rangle$ I have that $a= t[k]_n$ and $b=s[k_n]$ for $t,s \in \Bbb Z$. Now $$a+(-b)=t[k]_n - s[k]_n =  [tk-sk]_n=[(t-s)k]_n \in \langle [k]_n \rangle$$ as $(t-s)$ is an integer. Now for $x \in \langle [k]_n \rangle$ and $y \in \Bbb Z_n $ I have that $xy=t[k]_n \cdot [m]_n = [tkm]_n \in \langle [k]_n \rangle$ and $yx = [mtk]_n \in \langle [k]_n \rangle$. But how am I to know what operation should I consider with the cyclic group?

Comment: In every group, $\langle a\rangle =\{a^k\mid k\in  \Bbb Z\}$, where $a^2:=a\circ a$. In an additive group this is $a\circ a=a+a=2a$. So you know it for the additive group of $\Bbb Z_n$. An ideal $I$ in a ring $R$ by definition means that $(I,+)$ is a subgroup of the additive group $(R,+)$ satisfying ...

Comment: So I'm looking at $\langle [k]_n \rangle = \{t[k]_n \mid t \in \Bbb Z\}$ in this case?